Cannot send email to group of people
I saw interesting case in Azure DevOps which looks like some kind of limitation. When I set my business email in variable group like that:

And change applicable piece of code in this way:
stages:
    - stage: DEVApproval
      displayName: 'DEV Approval Gate'
      variables:
        - group: MY_APP
      jobs:
        - template: /manual_validation.yml@Pipelines
          parameters:
            email: $(email)

After a while I get the email to my business outlook account, so it works fine.
When I set in variable group the PDL taken from outlook (there are several people with me), I didn't get email with approval. For testing purposes I keep my email, however we need to have at least two person for Approval Gate to accept.

Contact your email service administrators. There might be rules preventing outside emails to be sent to a group.

Ok, I will do that. Thank you.
